# Does this AppendFormat have any value?

Tags: c#, .net, format, stringbuilder

I'm currently working on a project that was written a few years ago.

I ran into this line:

```
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", value);
```

As far as I can see, the fact it is being "formatted" makes no difference. There are no other characters being inserted, just *value*.

Why would the programmer write this line as **AppendFormat**, when it could have been written using **Append**, with less code?

*value* is a string.

Comment: Depends on the coder - it could be that they simply did it out of habit.  Are there other lines of code in the same place that do use it in the expected manner?  You are correct that it makes no difference though.

Comment: @Archer Ah, that would explain it I guess. I thought it may be more interesting than habit :( 

I have just searched the project, there are a few areas that use AppendFormat correctly.

Comment: I only guess that because I'm guilty of something similar.  If I have a string over multiple lines and I prefix *any* of the lines with a `$` then I "have to" do the same to all the others, even though it's functionally pointless.  It just lines them all up which I find easier to look at.

Comment: No, this has no value. I would recommend changing it to a simple `Append` to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: @Archer, I do the same!

Comment: @DavidG Have done, thanks all

Comment: I would suggest not prefixing with `$` when it isn't needed :) Put in an extra space if you must.

Comment: @NetMage - Why not use a `$` in the way I described?  Do you have a good reason, other than not preferring to see it, like I do?

Comment: @Archer Presence of the `$` implies intention to use substitution/formatting, though the compiler at least optimizes away the unnecessary `$`, it doesn't make for very good self documenting code. Should you then add a comment `// substitution not used here` ?

Comment: @Archer What is RestSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for this example. I found the line and had a look at the source control history.

The programmer essentially completely rewrote the method, but kept some lines in there (this included).

I can only guess that the programmer forgot to revert the line back to .Append after removing the value initially in there.

A bug without consequence, nightmare fuel.